# How to create Terminal Services Server add in (virtual channel) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, terminal-services, virtual-channel

I'm trying to create a dll as add in to Terminal Server to create a virtual channel communication with the server.

I found this example (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16374/How-to-Write-a-Terminal-Services-Add-in-in-Pure-C), which unfortunately doesn't works on 64 bit client (on 32 bit client working properly). I followed all the instructions of the author but nothing.

Can someone who has used this example help me?

Thanks, Luigi.

Comment: I'm trying to do similar thing using `UnmanagedExports` extension. This allows me to use `DllExport` to x64. I'm struggling with second part-server application that is started on RDP desktop. If You want to exchange some experience please leave a comment with Your email and I'll write You back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
You need to download the new version of the application (available [here](http://esilo.pl/TSAddinInCS.zip)) and in Visual Studio project properties , *Build events* tab replace **/$(PlatformName)** with **/x64** constant in *Post-build events command line* box. With the environment variable it doesn't works.

Thanks.

Comment: Dead link (as viewed on 2019-03-22)

Answer (score 2):

He has improved the program further at codeplex:

http://rdpaddins.codeplex.com/